The database cannot be opened at this time
The .Ick file for the output database D:/babar/Abaqus/Simu//1.odb indicates that the Analysis Input File Processor is currently modifying the database.
The database cannot be opened at this time.
I am trying to a 2000 simulation in Abaqus through Python scriptin, but after some simulation, I am getting this error message.
How to resolve this.

The issue could be because the analysis is not yet completed as Abaqus still opened ODB file in writing mode, hence not allowing you edit it. So, you need to check whether the analysis is completed. To check it, you can make use of waitForCompletion command and job status attribute. 
As you are using Abaqus python scripting to submit the jobs, you must be creating a job object then submitting using submit.
This job object has status attribute which indicates status of the analysis. Possible values are SUBMITTED, RUNNING, ABORTED, TERMINATED, COMPLETED, CHECK_RUNNING, and CHECK_COMPLETED.
from abaqusConstants import COMPLETED

# assume 'job' is job object.
# Submit the job
job.submit()

# Wait for the job to complete. No further lines get executes until job completes/aborts etc..
job.waitForCompletion()

# Check the job status before proceeding the post-processing
if job.status == COMPLETED:
    # Do post-processing...

